# Swift 2.1: Realm query fails with new line character

Tags: swift, nsstring, nspredicate, realm, swift2

I am trying to query realm for an object with a filter condition and it keeps failing for strings with new line characters

```
results = realm.objects(LocalizedString).filter(filterString!)
```

Here filterString contains the string

```
"tuvEnglish = 'Ndjdj\n' AND tuvThai = 'Ndjdj\n'"
```

This fails with the error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "tuvEnglish = 'Ndjdj
' AND tuvThai = 'Ndjdj
'"'
```

How should I fix this? Please help.

Comment: Just checking....  You want to specifically search for the New Line character encoding?

Or are you looking for a string that when the query string includes a new line it breaks your app?  Could you not remove any "new lines" before you commit the search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass the strings as dedicated arguments and not built-in to the format string like that:

```
 results = realm.objects(LocalizedString).filter("tuvEnglish = %@ AND tuvThai = %@", "Ndjdj\n", "Ndjdj\n")
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot! :)